# Error "Given transaction number * does not match" in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, acid

I want to modify two schema while adding data. For that I used ACID transaction of mongodb with nodejs as follow. But, when I run program it displays the error like

```
(node:171072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Given transaction number 3 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is 2
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/user/Projects/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:272:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at MessageStream.emit (domain.js:470:12)
```

```
addData = async(request: Request, response: Response) => {
   const session = await stockSchema.startSession()
   try {
       const userData = request.body
       let data = {}

       const transaction = await session.withTransaction(async() => {
           try {
               userData.products.map(async(item: any) => {
                   await inventorySchema.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: item.materialID }, { $inc: {qty: -item.qty }}, { session });
                }); 
                data = new stockSchema(userData);
                await data.save({ session });  
           } catch (error) {
               await session.abortTransaction()
               throw new Error("Could not create data. Try again.");
           }
       });
       if (transaction) {
           session.endSession()
           return returnData(response, data, 'Data created successfully.');
       } else {
           throw new Error("Could not create data. Try again.");
       }
   } catch (error: any) {
       session.endSession();
       return Error(response, error.message, {});
   }
}
```

Comment: Does withTransaction now support being called with async like that?

Answer (score 2):

So you might have figured out the answer to this already, but anyway, after months of frustration, and no clear answer on the internet, i finally figured it out.

The problem with your code above is that you are passing session into a database operation (the `.findOneAndUpdate` function above) that is running within `.map` . Meaning, your 'transaction session' is being used concurrently, which is what is causing the error. read this: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/concurrency-in-mongodb-transactions/14945 (it explains why concurrency with transactions creates a bit of a mess.)

Anyway, instead of `.map`, use a recursive function that fires each DB operation one after another rather than concurrently, and all your problems will be solved.

You could use a function something like this:

```
const executeInQueue = async ({
    dataAry, //the array that you .map through
    callback, //the function that you fire inside .map
    idx = 0,
    results = [],
  }) => {
    if (idx === dataAry.length) return results;
    //else if idx !== dataAry.length
    let d = dataAry[idx];
  
    try {
      let result = await callback(d, idx);
  
      results.push(result);

      return executeInQueue({
        dataAry,
        callback,
        log,
        idx: idx + 1,
        results,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log({ err });
      return results.push("error");
    }
  };
```